# Can't find source code for building mysql

Tags: mysql, installation, source-code

I'm trying to follow the [instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/source-installation.html) for building MySQL from source. They guide me to a [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/getting-mysql.html) where I can download the latest GA. I end up at the downloads [page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/), where I can download `mysql-5.6.19-osx10.7-x86_64.tar.gz` for my mac, and then untar and unzip.

All good so far. But when I try to `cmake .` per the instructions, I get an error saying that it can't find `CMakeLists.txt`. Poking around looking for that, I've discovered that the download doesn't come with any actual source code except `.h` files. In fact, the download looks like an already-built setup with binaries such as `mysqld` already there.

I am probably missing something obvious, but I can't figure out where I'm supposed to get the full source code and the makefile, if not from the links provided under the title, "Installing MySQL Using a Standard Source Distribution". Anyone have an idea?

Comment: you've downloaded compiled binaries for MacOS. What you need is http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.19.tar.gz

Comment: @akuzminsky Thanks so much! Just for my own enlightenment, how could I have known to go there? Am I totally reading the wrong instructions, or is it that the instructions are faulty?

Comment: When you go to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ it detects your MacOS and suggests you to download the binaries for MacOS. But as long as you want to compile MySQL from the source code you need to select "Source Code" in the drop-down list and then download archive "Generic Linux"

Comment: However I must note if there is no good reason to compile MySQL from the source it's better to use binaries.

Comment: @akuzminsky Again, thanks! I saw "Mac OS X" in the dropdown and didn't look any further, haha.

Answer (score -1):

Funny - I'm just doing this myself now (assuming Linux (as per Alex Kuzminsky - I use Xubuntu - no heavy GUI desktop).

Get the source (all source downloads [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) (select from dropdown), Linux source [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=452276)).

Run (depends on your Linux distro)

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
sudo apt-get install bison flex
sudo apt-get install libaio1
sudo apt-get install g++ (Ooops!)
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

This was all I needed to do after a fresh (Oracle Virtual Box) install of Xubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Then, what I do is follow the instructions [here](http://www.skysql.com/blogs/claudio/compiling-debugging-mariadband-mysql-eclipse-scratch-part-1-setup-building-environme-0).

Create a directory "sandbox" beside mysql-5.6.16.

```
cmake ../mysql-5.6.19
make
make package
```

then install the mysql-5.6.19-linux_64.tar.gz package (or whatever it's called)

Works nicely for those of use who want to control things and even run several MySQL servers on the same machine using different ports for example.